# Spyder Python Yfinance Module Not Found

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, yfinance

I've installed yfinance successfully and it is located in the python modules as seen below:

[image]

Unfortunately, Spyder is producing the following "module not found" error message.

[image]

Despite uninstalling and reinstalling yfinance, locating it in with the other modules it still isn't being found.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing older or newer version of Jupyter. I've had a few problems with importing and going back to an older version of Jupyter always helped. Like there was something wrong with their last update.